# Split python string by predifned indices

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string that I'd like to split in specific places into a list of strings. The split points are stored in a separate split list. For example:

```
test_string = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"
split_points = [0, 3, 8, 13, 16, 21, 25, 28, 32]
```

...should return:

```
>>> ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

So far I have this as the solution, but it looks incredibly convoluted for how simple the task is:

```
split_points.append(len(test_string))
print [test_string[start_token:end_token] for start_token, end_token in [(split_points[i], split_points[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(split_points)-1)]]
```

Any good string functions that do the job, or is this the easiest way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Python doesn't have `out-of-the-box` split at position feature, if you ask for built-in function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
>>> map(lambda x: test_string[slice(*x)], zip(split_points, split_points[1:]+[None]))
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

We're `zip`ing `split_points` with a shifted self, to create a list of all consecutive pairs of slice indexes, like `[(0,3), (3,8), ...]`. We need to add the last slice `(32,None)` manually, since `zip` terminates when the shortest sequence is exhausted.

Then we `map` over that list a simple lambda slicer. Note the `slice(*x)` which creates a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) object, e.g. `slice(0, 3, None)` which we can use to slice the sequence (string) with standard the [item getter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem) (`__getslice__` in Python 2).

A little bit more Pythonic implementation could use a list comprehension instead of `map`+`lambda`:

```
>>> [test_string[i:j] for i,j in zip(split_points, split_points[1:] + [None])]
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

Comment: Why the lambda? You can unpack the tuple in a list comprehension and just do `[test_string[i:j] for i,j in zip(split_points, split_points[1:] + [None])]`

Comment: You're right, when thinking "functional", I always astray to `map` and `lambda`. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

This may be less convoluted:

```
>> test_string = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"
>> split_points = [0, 3, 8, 13, 16, 21, 25, 28, 32]
>> split_points.append(len(test_string))
>> print([test_string[i: j] for i, j in zip(split_points, split_points[1:])])
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 0):

First draft:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(split_points):
    try:
        print(test_string[i:split_points[idx+1]])
    except IndexError:
        print(test_string[i:])
```