# Regex using increasing sequence of numbers Python

Tags: python, regex, string, sequential

Say I have a string:

```
teststring =  "1.3 Hello how are you 1.4 I am fine, thanks 1.2 Hi There 1.5 Great!"
```

That I would like as:

```
testlist = ["1.3 Hello how are you", "1.4 I am fine, thanks 1.2 Hi There", "1.5 Great!"]
```

Basically, splitting only on increasing digits where the difference is .1 (i.e. 1.2 to 1.3).

Is there a way to split this with regex but only capturing increasing sequential numbers? I wrote code in python to sequentially iterate through using a custom re.compile() for each one and it is okay but extremely unwieldy.

Something like this (where parts1_temp is a given list of the x.x. numbers in the string):

```
parts1_temp = ['1.3','1.4','1.2','1.5']
parts_num =  range(int(parts1_temp.split('.')[1]), int(parts1_temp.split('.')[1])+30)
parts_search = ['.'.join([parts1_temp.split('.')[0], str(parts_num_el)]) for parts_num_el in parts_num]
#parts_search should be ['1.3','1.4','1.5',...,'1.32']

for k in range(len(parts_search)-1):
    rxtemp = re.compile(r"(?:"+str(parts_search[k])+")([\s\S]*?)(?=(?:"+str(parts_search[k+1])+"))", re.MULTILINE)
    parts_fin = [match.group(0) for match in rxtemp.finditer(teststring)]
```

But man is it ugly. Is there a way to do this more directly in regex? I imagine this is feature that someone would have wanted at some point with regex but I can't find any ideas on how to tackle this (and maybe it is not possible with pure regex).

Comment: `But man is it ugly` yep... It'll be uglier with a single regex too!

Comment: Haha maybe. I'm very very far from a regex expert so I don't know

Comment: What about the scenario "1.3 ..... 1.4 ..... 1.2 ...... 1.3....." Would you match the second instance of 1.3?.

Comment: You can do that with Perl. I doubt you can do it with Python `re`/`regex` (at least "nicely").

Comment: I suggest two steps: (1) overgenerate with RegEx, (2) postprocess to fix errors. Ie. you split before each x.x occurrence (with a RegEx containing `\d\.\d`), then check pairs of neighboring parts to reattach what was erroneously split apart.

Comment: PrestonM no I would not want it to match that

Comment: Later, you may find this [interesting for study](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306590/match-list-of-incrementing-integers-using-regex).

Comment: Just split on every `\d\.\d` number, then test if it's increasing and if not, push the concatenated string+number+next_string back on the parser. (Ultimately, why is this text formatted in this weird way, and what are you trying to achieve after you split it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method uses `finditer` to find all locations of `\d+\.\d+`, then tests whether the match was numerically greater than the previous. If the test is true it appends the index to the `indices` array.

The last line uses list comprehension as taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45104921/3600709) to split the string on those given indices.

#### Original Method

This method ensures the previous match is smaller than the current one. This doesn't work sequentially, instead, it works based on number size. So assuming a string has the numbers `1.1, 1.2, 1.4`, it would split on each occurrence since each number is larger than the last.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##TY@xTsMwEIbn@CmOTI4aWQ2FJYIVysLElmaw2ktyJbGtiytSXj5caCRYrLP1f9/9DtfYebebZxqC5wiMSpE70RFHeIaqVmNkcq3MkBZmB3vsew@d/wLLCFd/gcI8wBvYARpymEPsrPsc5fUe9gQfHUqsMI/wymjjXaoYW5xEx2iOfgjUo@b0cNocjBxppno7xpfe2yiZrVKNZxiAHPxyplm6RWR9q5WVKllkzQLowbTsL0FnmUqogT/TE0wSTP6rJ7mv/zQ2BHQnwcdoOeqt8CqIPurqtqai8lzDUoXy81Lmm4Je6RzWoSrKelO9e4d1Vothnn8A)

```
import re

indices = []
string =  "1.3 Hello how are you 1.4 I am fine, thanks 1.2 Hi There 1.5 Great!"
regex = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+")
lastFloat = 0

for m in regex.finditer(string):
    x = float(m.group())
    if lastFloat < x:
        lastFloat = x
        indices.append(m.start(0))

print([string[i:j] for i,j in zip(indices, indices[1:]+[None])])
```

Outputs: `['1.3 Hello how are you ', '1.4 I am fine, thanks 1.2 Hi There ', '1.5 Great!']`

---

## Edit

#### Sequential Method

This method is very similar to the original, however, on the case of `1.1, 1.2, 1.4`, it wouldn't split on `1.4` since it doesn't follow sequentially given the `.1` sequential separator.

The method below only differs in the `if` statement, so this logic is fairly customizable to whatever your needs may be.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##TZCxbsMgFEXn8BW3nkCxUNw0S6Subbp06uZ4QMmzTWoDwkRN@vPuo8mQBT3g3sMR4Zp679bzbMfgY0IkIaw72gNNeEXdiClF6zqeUVR6jR0Ng0fvf2Ai4erPqPQLPmBGtNZRidQb9z3x6TN2Fl89cazSG7xHMumpEJE6ujAukj74MdiBZCz2x@Ve81IoMZgpvQ3eJM6shGh9xAjr8N/TbXZLFOVNS23FIsPaXJCj7qI/B6mUWNgW8gHFLAVGyUueOeWOD9dL6KpEpTJu8Shw4f39N7QJgbg16imZmOSKXxGBJZKsbzK13Z4aZGFbnrLyrw3y3i5xH@pq2yzrT@@oUQ0T5vkP)

```
import re

indices = []
string =  "1.3 Hello how are you 1.4 I am fine, thanks 1.2 Hi There 1.5 Great!"
regex = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+")
lastFloat = 0

for m in regex.finditer(string):
    x = float(m.group())
    if (lastFloat == 0) or (x == round(lastFloat + .1, 1)):
        lastFloat = x
        indices.append(m.start(0))

print([string[i:j] for i,j in zip(indices, indices[1:]+[None])])
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The output is what the OP expects.

Comment: @sfortney it's not splitting on every `x.x` it's splitting on `x.x` if `x.x` is larger than the last

Comment: My bad. Changed my vote sorry. Actually I think this might be a neat way to do it. I was hoping for a slightly more regex-y solution though.

Comment: Oh also this doesn't only catch iterations by 1 which is something I asked for in the question

Comment: @sfortney Oh I get it now! Give me a couple of minutes to fix it. Sorry, didn't see you want only increasing of 0.1

Comment: @sfortney please see my edit. I've altered this to work sequentially. I've kept the original in case it helps future readers.

Comment: Yeah that's probably about the best you can do I think. I was really hoping there was a secret regex command I didn't know about but that doesn't seem to be the case. :)

Comment: @sfortney unfortunately regex doesn’t know what’s sequential. It’s a hack to get sequences working in regex alone. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589051/3600709) for matching sequential alphabetic letters in regex alone

Comment: Hey ctwheels one more quick question, how would this change if the string was "Section 1.3 Hello how are you Section 1.4 I am fine, thanks Section 1.2 Hi There Section 1.5 Great!" and the desired output, ["Section 1.3 Hello how are you", "Section 1.4 I am fine, thanks Section 1.2 Hi There", "Section 1.5 Great!"]

Comment: @sfortney you would change the regex to `Section (\d+\.\d+)` and set `x = float(m.group(1))` instead of `m.group()` as seen [here](https://tio.run/##TZCxbsMgFEXn8BW3nkCxUNw0S6Subbp06uZ4QMmzTWoDwkRN@vPuo8mQBT3g3sMR4Zp679bzbMfgY0IkIaw72gNNeEXdiClF6zqeUVR6jR0Ng0fvf2Ai4erPqPQLPmBGtNZRidQb9z3x6TN2Fl89cazSG7xHMumpEJE6ujAukj74MdiBZCz2x@Ve81IoMZgpvQ3eJM6shGh9xAjr8N/TbXZLFOVNS23FIsPaXJCj7qI/B6mUWNgW8gHFLAVGyUueOeWOD9dL6KpEpTJu8Shw4f39N7QJgbg16imZmOSKXxGBJZKsbzK13Z4aZGFbnrLyrw3y3i5xH@pq2yzrT@@oUQ0T5vkP)

Comment: Never mind your solution does work. I was just putting it into a function and getting some weirdness from that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Doing this with a regex *only* seems overly complex. What about this processing:

```
import re

teststring =  "1.3 Hello how are you 1.4 I am fine, thanks 1.2 Hi There 1.5 Great!" 
res = []
expected = None
for s in re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\D+', teststring):
    if s[0].isdigit() and expected is None:
        expected = s
        fmt = '{0:.' + str(max(0, len(s) - (s+'.').find('.') - 1)) + 'f}'
        inc = float(re.sub(r'\d', '0', s)[0:-1] + '1')
    if s == expected:
        res.append(s)
        expected = fmt.format(float(s) + inc)
    elif expected:
        res[-1] = res[-1] + s

print (res)
```

This also works if the numbers happen to have 2 decimals or more, or none.

Comment: Just FYI this doesn't seem to work going from say 8.9 to 8.10. I could be wrong but I think that is correct

Comment: It would go to from 8.9 to 9.0, which I assumed was what was expected (you wrote: *"where the difference is .1"*). If it has to be different the logic would have to change a bit. But anyway, I suppose you already have your answer, since you accepted one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also mutate the string so that a marker is placed next to the digit if it is part of the increasing sequence. Then, you can split at that marker:

```
import re
teststring =  "1.3 Hello how are you 1.4 I am fine, thanks 1.2 Hi There 1.5 Great!" 
numbers = re.findall('[\.\d]+', teststring)
final_string = re.sub('[\.\d]+', '{}', teststring).format(*[numbers[0]]+[numbers[i] if numbers[i] < numbers[i-1] else '*'+numbers[i] for i in range(1, len(numbers))]).split(' *')
```

Output:

```
['1.3 Hello how are you', '1.4 I am fine, thanks 1.2 Hi There', '1.5 Great!']
```